# What is the correct way to express this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> Man: **I have seeing you with more ladies a lot lately**.

**Meaning of sentence**: Man is asking another man that Now a days he is roaming with more ladies.

What is the correct way to express this sentence?

Comment: Should the man be asking a question, or should he be stating an observation?

Comment: There is a mistake in bolded sentence & Yes, man should be asking question to other man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, this is a statement of observation, not a question. The speaker is implying the question "why have I been seeing you with more ladies," but we wouldn't want to end the sentence with a question mark. This ifs a perfectly acceptable usage. The man is asking a question without actually asking a question because of the sensitive nature of the subject.

But to answer your question, you are looking for the ***present perfect continuous*** tense of the verb *to see*, which is "have been seeing."

> I have **been** seeing you with more ladies a lot lately.

Answer (score 1):

You've [indicated that you are looking for a question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/121911/what-is-the-correct-way-to-express-this-sentence#comment245632_121911).

Assuming the man has definitely seen his friend with more ladies lately and wants to know *why*, the simplest form of a question I can think of would be:

> Why have I been seeing you with more ladies lately?

Or, alternatively:

> Why have I been seeing you with so many ladies lately?

The second example focuses more on the fact that the man is with a lot of ladies, the first focuses more on the fact that the man is with more ladies than usual.

I think it's pretty much implied that the man has been seeing the other man "a lot" (or "often", in this case) here, as otherwise he would not be asking this question (and also "lately" here sort of implies the change was recent and noticeable enough to ask about), so something like *"Why have I been seeing you with more ladies a lot lately?"* seems like it would be a bit too verbose. It doesn't add much to the question.

---

The other way I can interpret your post is perhaps you want the man to ask his friend *if* he has been with more ladies lately. In that case, something like this:

> Have I been seeing you with more ladies lately?

There, the man may *think* he has seen his friend with more ladies lately, but is not sure and wants to confirm.

If you were to ask:

> Have you been with more ladies lately?

This means the man is just wondering if his friend has been with more ladies lately, but hasn't necessarily *seen* his friend with his own eyes and wants to confirm.